# css working fine chrome but not in mozilla by using zend

Tags: html, css

Im working on a signin form.I have given all properties by testin it on googlechrome.After completing the form I checked it in mozilla.the dimensions I have specified are completely changed especially height.Can I know the reason behind this.
here is my code

```
input
{
  padding: 13px 14%;
 }
#email-wrapper #email-label
{  
  border: 1px solid #e5d4c2;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
display: inline-block;
height: 39px;
line-height: 36px;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: 0;
width: 36px;
}

    #email-wrapper #email-label label 
{
  background: url("~/application/modules/User/externals/images/mail.png") no-repeat              scroll 19px 13px #FFFFFF;
       background-size: 15px 15px;   
    }
#email-wrapper #email-label label
{
 color:transparent;
   }
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what exactly is going wrong in mozilla?

Comment: the height of input elements change a bit inthe sense nearly 2 to 3pixels.If I changed it for firefox then chrome was disturbing

Comment: can you please post your html code too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please Use this CSS and Cross Browser :**

```
input{
    padding: 13px 14%;
}

#email-wrapper #email-label{

    border: 1px solid #e5d4c2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px; 
         -o-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px; 
        -ms-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
            border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 39px;
    line-height: 36px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 36px;
}

#email-wrapper #email-label label {
    background-image: url("~/application/modules/User/externals/images/mail.png") 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-position:19px 13px;
    background-size: 15px 15px;   
}
#email-wrapper #email-label label{
    color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: I second that it would most likely be a cross browser issue, nothing like trying to develop something as simple as a web page but having to have 4 times the code/handlers.

Answer (score 1):

After watching the CSS Code My assumption is that input field height is different on both browser.. by giving the style to input field your problem should solve..

you need to add these property in your input field..

```
input
{
  padding: 13px 14%;
  border:1px solid #666;
  border-radius:5px;
 }
```

I hope this will work for you.

Regards,

Comment: thanx for the suggestion you have given .But the problem is by giving percentage in padding

Comment: ideally you should use %, or px or em values... please don't use a combination.